# How do I make Perl’s system() format arguments using scientific notation?

Tags: perl, floating-point, scientific-notation

From my Perl program, I am trying to run another command written in C using `system`. The command requires several arguments: a string, a float, two integers, a pair of floats, and another string. I am running this as

```
my $arg1="electron";
my $arg2=0.511;
# more definitions
system("./fermions $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 " .
       "$arg5 $arg6 \"string\" > outfile.out");
```

I need to vary `$arg5` to be several different float values. I made it work by setting `$arg5="1.0e5"` and then running an if-statement in the for-loop to change the value as a string. I would like to be able to do this as floats, and tried

```
system("./fermions $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 " .
       "%e $arg6 \"string\" >outfile.out",
       $arg5);
```

but that did not work. Is there another alternative, or is my if-statement option the only one?

Comment: Please consider using `system LIST` or `system {PROGRAM} LIST` [invocation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).  That will be much safer when, someday, after many refactors, `$arg2` becomes `"; rm -rf /"`.  You won't be able to use shell output redirection, but you can always open `outfile.out` yourself and dup to STDOUT or wrap `./fermions` in a shell script to capture output.

Comment: Understood. I will amend my code for this, but I am, at this point, asking this question for future use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use printf notation (like "%e"), you need to use the Perl `sprintf` builtin. Otherwise you just end up passing "%e" as a literal argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** You should *always* check the return value from Perl’s [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function to determine whether the command failed.

Use Perl’s [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to format the float values as in the code below. Yes, you may be able to get away with using the command as your format specifier, but you’re likely to get surprising results if the command has stray % characters elsewhere. Using two steps is safer.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @float_values = (1.0e5, 3.14159, 2.71828);

for my $f (@float_values) {
  my $arg5 = sprintf "%e", $f;

  system(qq[./fermions $arg5 "string" >> outfile.out]) == 0
    or warn "$0: fermions failed";
}
```

In case you aren’t familiar with the syntax, [`qq[...]`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) works like a double-quoted string, but the different delimiter means you don’t have to escape double-quotes in your command.

Note that I elided the other arguments for typographical purposes, but you can interpolate them along with the value of `$arg5`. Another subtle change is the switch to `>>` for appending rather than `>` for clobbering.

Using a stand-in for `fermions`

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
$" = "][";
warn "[@ARGV]\n";
```

the output of the two programs running together is

```
[1.000000e+05][string]
[3.141590e+00][string]
[2.718280e+00][string]
```

With respect to terminology, a system call refers to a low-level request for service from the operating system, *e.g.*, `open`, `close`, `unlink`, and so on. Although Perl’s system function makes use of system calls, the two concepts are distinct.

To be *really* safe about the shell not fudging your command-line arguments, use the techniques described in the [“Safe Pipe Opens” section of perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens). Perl’s [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) functions bypass the shell when given a list of arguments rather than a single string containing the entire command.

Your situation is a little trickier because you want to redirect the standard output. The code below forks a child, sets the child’s `STDOUT` to append to `outfile.out`, and then runs `fermion` with [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) in the child. The parent waits for the child to exit and reports any failure.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @float_values = (1.0e5, 3.14159, 2.71828);

for my $f (@float_values) {
  my $arg5 = sprintf "%e", $f;

  my $pid = fork;
  if (defined $pid) {
    if ($pid == 0) {
      my $path = "outfile.out";
      open STDOUT, ">>", $path or die "$0: open $path: $!";
      exec "./fermions", $arg5, "string" or die "$0: exec: $!";
    }
    else {
      local $!;
      my $pid = waitpid $pid, 0;
      warn "$0: waitpid: $!" if $pid == -1 && $!;
      warn "$0: fermion exited " . ($? >> 8) if $?;
    }
  }
  else {
    die "$0: fork: $!";
  }
}
```